# Pivot Table By One Column And Multiple Aggregates

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, pivot, aggregate-functions

I prepared the following report. It displays three columns (AccruedInterest, Tip & CardRevenue) by month for a given year. Now I want to "Rotate" the result so that `StartDate` value turn into 12 columns.

**I have this:**

[image]

**I need this:**
[image]

I have tried pivoting the table but I need multiple columns to be aggregated as you see.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpivot your data and the pivot.
Note: I put in my own values in your table as to make each unique so you know the data is correct.

```
--Create YourTable
SELECT * INTO YourTable
FROM
(
        SELECT  CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE) StartDate,
            607.834 AS AccruedInterest,
            1 AS Tip,
            3 AS CardRevenue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CAST('2015-02-01' AS DATE) StartDate,
            643.298 AS AccruedInterest,
            16.8325 AS Tip,
            5 AS CardRevenue
) A;
GO

--This pivots your data
SELECT *
FROM
(
    --This unpivots your data using cross apply
    SELECT col,val,StartDate
    FROM YourTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT 'AccruedInterest', CAST(AccruedInterest AS VARCHAR(100))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Tip', CAST(Tip AS VARCHAR(100))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'CardRevenue', CAST(CardRevenue AS VARCHAR(100))
    ) A(col,val)
) B

PIVOT
(
    MAX(val) FOR startdate IN([2015-01-01],[2015-02-01])
) pvt
```

Results:

```
col               2015-01-01   2015-02-01
AccruedInterest   607.834      643.298
CardRevenue       3            5
Tip               1.0000       16.8325
```